# how to get position of specific post array from ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

My array from a ajax request looks like this on a print_r POST, how can i access the  posititions to save it in a PHP variable

```
Array ( [geslachten] => Array ( [0] => Dhr. [1] => Mevr. ) [voornamen] => 
Array ( [0] => G.F. [1] => F. ) [achternamen] => Array ( [0] => d [1] => f ) 
[geboortedata] => Array ( [0] => 25-10-1993 [1] => 14-04-1994 ) )
```

I need all the data from `geslachten`, `voornamen`, `achternamen` and `geboortedata`, and put them into seperate php variables like this: `$geslachten`, `$voornamen`, `$achternamen` and `$geboortedata`

jquery code:

```
 $("#submitboeking").click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();


        //Cursisten

            var voornamen = [];
            var achternamen = [];
            var geslachten = [];
            var geboortedata = [];



        $("[id^='txtCursistVoornaam']").each(function() {
            voornamen.push($(this).val());
        });
        $("[id^='txtCursistAchternaam']").each(function() {
            achternamen.push($(this).val());
        });
        $("[id^='radCursistGeslacht']:checked").each(function() {
            geslachten.push($(this).val());
        });
        $("[id^='txtCursistGeboortedatum']").each(function() {
            geboortedata.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.post('/wp-content/themes/tweb/processboeking.php',
         {

                 'geslachten': geslachten,
                 'voornamen': voornamen,
                 'achternamen': achternamen,
                 'geboortedata': geboortedata,

            })
            .done(function(data)
             { 
                //  console.log(data)
                $('#overzicht').html(data);


            }).fail(function(data) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            });

        var li_count = $('.nav-tabs li').length;
        var current_active = $('.nav-tabs li.active').index();
        if (current_active < li_count) {
            $('.nav-tabs li.active').next('li').find('a').attr('data-toggle', 'tab').tab('show');
            var txt = $(".oplselect option:selected").text();
            var val = $(".oplselect option:selected").val();
            $('.showoplnaam').html('Uw selectie: ' + txt);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access those values as below;

```
$geslachten = $_POST['geslachten'];
$voornamen= $_POST['voornamen'];
$achternamen= $_POST['achternamen'];
$geboortedata= $_POST['geboortedata'];
```

If you want to get each item inside the array you retrieved, you can iterate through the array as below.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($geslachten); $i++) {
    echo $geslachten[$i];
}
```

Same for other arrays also.

Comment: i got 4 different arrays and send with post. How can i put the array geslachten or voornamen in a php array geslachten or voornamen? check my edit

Comment: Are you posting each array separately?

Comment: i dont know how it works when u put the 4 arrays into a ajax post. Did u see my edit?

Comment: Then you can get each array as `$geslachten = $_POST['geslachten'];` and so on.

Comment: if i do this it shows an empty array, because i think you cant echo an array. $geslachten = $_POST['geslachten'];
echo $geslachten; how can i check if geslachten is filled now?

Comment: use var_dump() instead

Comment: thanks got it working with $geslachten = $_POST['geslachten'];